# Landing page in Joomla with problems on iOS

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

Can someone help me here?

I cannot understand why ONLY in iOS the "Autenticar" button does not work! :(

http://www.select.pt.la/

It works on "ALL" browsers in Windows and Android, but in iOS... nothing!

Can't figure this out.

EDIT:

Since this is a test platform, you can login with

User: demo
Pass: demo

Comment: Pedro this question might be better suited for http://joomla.stackexchange.com Anyway, what do you mean "doesn't work"? What happens?

Comment: @moomoochoo Well, if you click, button simply does nothing at all. It's like if it's not even there! :(

Comment: OK. I checked your site and got the following message "A sua sessão expirou, por favor volte a autenticar-se." I'm not sure exactly what it is saying, maybe "Your session has expired please re-authenticate?"

Comment: This isn't a solution per se, but if you enable the debug console on the iphone you will see lots and lots of Javascript errors. By fixing these you may fix your problem.

 - "ReferenceError:Can't find variable:JQuery"
 - "TypeError:'null' is not an object"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some serious issues on that site which could be having all kinds of strange effects. You are running javascripts that need jquery, and jquery is not loaded

Why not use this free plugin to see if it stops the errors, and as a secondary function fixes your button

[JQuery Easy](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/performance/jquery-scripts/18327)